# I need help understanding how a Power BI Matrix visualization works

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am building a Matrix and need to add a column showing the total of the Matrix in all rows.  But when I add the measure it blanks all the values on all other columns.

```
TtlRevenuetoAllocate =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Contract[Revenue] ) - SUM ( Contract[Cost] ),
    ALL ( Contract[Unit] )
)
```

[image]

Comment: can you please add some more details? like some sample data in tabular format?

Comment: I just discovered that it actually is returning values for all divisions not only for the ones that I am filtering on.

Comment: @Francisco the use of ALL results in a table as your filter ignoring all other filter context, displaying the calculation for all units.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TtlRevenuetoAllocate :=
VAR RevSum =
    SUM ( Contract[Revenue] )
VAR Cost =
    SUM ( Contract[Cost] )
RETURN
    RevSum - Cost
```